# How to fill in form field, and submit, using javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

If I have an html document whose rough structure is

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body class="bodyclass" id="bodyid">
<div class="headerstuff">..stuff...</div>
<div class = "body">
<form action="http://example.com/login" id="login_form" method="post">
<div class="form_section">You can login here</div>
<div class="form_section">
<input xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="text" id="username"
       name="session[username_or_email]" tabindex="1" type="text" value="" />
</div>
<div class="form_section">etc</div>
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="buttons">
    <button type="submit" class="" name="" id="go" tabindex="3">Go</button>
    <button type="submit" class="" name="cancel" 
            id="cancel" tabindex="4">Cancel</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see that there is a username field and a Go button. How would I, using Javascript, fill in the username and press Go...?

I would prefer to use plain JS, rather than a library like jQuery.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but why are you filling in the xmlns property for both your input and div? That usually belongs in the `<html>` tag.

Comment: Any reason why you don't use `<input type="submit" />`? Your form will not work if JS is disabled.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('username').value="moo"
document.forms[0].submit()
```

Answer (score 25):

```
document.getElementById('username').value = 'foo';
document.getElementById('login_form').submit();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function simulateLogin(userName)
        {
            var userNameField = document.getElementById("username");
            userNameField.value = userName;
            var goButton = document.getElementById("go");
            goButton.click();
        }

        simulateLogin("testUser");
</script>
```

Comment: It is not a submit button. `goButton.click();` won't do anything.

Answer (score 3):

It would be something like:

```
document.getElementById("username").value="Username";
document.forms[0].submit()
```

Or similar
edit: you guys are too fast ;)

Answer (score 1):

This method helped me doing this task

```
document.forms['YourFormNameHere'].elements['NameofFormField'].value = "YourValue"
document.forms['YourFormNameHere'].submit();
```