# Script to fill browser form

Tags: forms, batch-file, fill

I have little business problem, I need to make a script to fill (not send) out browser forms(only simple textfields, checkboxes and drop downboxes).

I need to launch multiple windows with the same form with different data to speed up form filling

1. What kind of scripting/programming do I need to use to fulfill these needs(Batch, JS .. ) ?
2. I have knowledge only of java, and basic html,c,c++ ... so if I can get basic tutorials I would be grateful indeed.

I have bits of ideas of how this is possible - through IDs of various field on the page which I can access to edit their values, so I just need language specific tutorials/suggestions.

Batch would be preferable if possible, because i need to execute the script through a java swing program.

P.S : If this is of any relevance, only browser acceptable is IE

Answer (score 2):

dont think its possible through Batch,

I think easiest would be javaScript for this task. (chill js is pretty easy)

You can write a simple javaScript to fill in form
You should find [how to fill form through javaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683331/how-to-fill-in-form-field-and-submit-using-javascript) helpful

Then you can use `ScriptEngineManager` to execute javaScript from your java code.

This tutorial should be helpful :[execute javascript from java](http://metoojava.wordpress.com/2010/06/20/execute-javascript-from-java/)

Comment: some more questions arise :

1. Where do I code this in, notepad? And save it as what extension?---
2. The saved file, will I need to compile it using a compiler(or JS does not need any...I really don't have a clue about JS) ?---

2. How will I be able to launch multiple windows with the same URL using JS ?

Comment: To kickstart your javaScript skills read [javaScript tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) , 1) you could write it in notepad too. 2) javaScripts are saved by `.js` extension.

Comment: @Arjun  you can launch same urls in multiple windows/tabs. [ref](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) . I aint building the blocks for you. Build up your logic, what you want to do, break the problem and search, read tutorials. everything is out there.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure I'll do the rest myself

Comment: Sorry, to bug you again ... but the most important requirement was to use this script on another website, is that even possible with JS? Because I was able to do something of that sort with VBScript. I was able to edit forms of a sample webpage I made.

And just to clarify, I don't have any malicious intentions, only to speed up form filling

Comment: @Arjun : I dont get you what you mean. Also if there is some question a new one. you should post it in a new thread to get everyone attention and not just mine. P.S : I dont care if you have any malicious intentions too.

Answer (score 0):

You can't fill HTML-fields with a Batch-File. The easiest way is to use Javascript an [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) in Mozilla Firefox. You can find Tutorials [here](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Tutorials).

An other way to send data to an WebServer is to use in C/C++/Java Sockets and the HTML-Protocol.

Comment: I think OP mentions that only supported browser is IE

Comment: -1 , Also, what part of question does _An other way to send data to an WebServer is to use in C/C++/Java Sockets and the HTML-Protocol_ answers??