# Ionic - Angularjs - Autofill a form in InAppBrowser

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I am trying to autofill an in-app browser form based on the values stored in my database.

Use Case:

1. User Stored his Home Address and Phone Number in the app.
2. User is redirected to a form in the InApp browser that is requesting user's Home Address and Phone Number.

Assumption:  We already know the structure of the forms to be filled out and there are only about 10 forms.

Supported Platforms:  Android, iOS and Windows

Answer (score 0):

You could to this by injecting a JavaScript script on the In-App Browser Page that will fill programmaticaly the form. It is available by the method : [`executeScript`](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#inappbrowserexecutescript)

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
ref.executeScript('myscript.js', callback);
```

Comment: is there an example script I can see?

Comment: Take a look at this question (without the submit part) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683331/how-to-fill-in-form-field-and-submit-using-javascript